# I want to compare numbers after each iteration and return common number

Tags: javascript

How can I get one common number in each iteration for example :

```
2 ==> 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 36 ... 60
3 ==> 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60
4 ==> 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60
```

I want to loop through 2,3,4 and pause the loop if we get the same number in all elements.
Thank you in advance.

```
function smallestCommons(array) {
let arr = array.sort()
let newArr = [];

  for(let i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++){
    console.log('when i = ', i);
    for(let j = i; j <= arr[1]; j+= i){
       console.log(j)
    }
  }

 return newArr;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code a bit.
You can use this:

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3];
var arr2 = [8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 12];
var arr3 = [6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60];
var arr4 = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 36];
var arr5 = [6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60];
var arr6 = [8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60];

function smallestCommons(...arrays) {
  // let arr = array.sort();
  var newarr = [];
  var duplicates = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    newarr = newarr.concat(arrays[i]);
  }

  newarr = newarr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < newarr.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && newarr[i] == newarr[i - 1] && !duplicates.includes(newarr[i])) {
      duplicates.push(newarr[i]);
    }
  }

  return duplicates.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });
}

console.log(smallestCommons(arr1, arr2, arr3));
```

Comment: I wanna a range of numbers in a given array [2,4] was just an simple example,
what if you get [1,24]

Comment: I updated the code so you can have as much array as you want.

Comment: thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Thanks, consider accepting if its useful for you

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr1=[4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,36],
arr2 =[6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60],
arr3 =[8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52,56,60];

//Below code finds common numbers from the above 3 arrays and add that number in newArr
//and newArr values are printed at the end

var newArr=[];

  for(let i =0; i < arr1.length; i++){
     if(arr2.includes(arr1[i]) && arr3.includes(arr1[i]) ){
        newArr.push(arr1[i]);
     }
  }
console.log(newArr)
```